# Export all styles to the css file using office-ui-fabric-react components

Tags: office-ui-fabric

Is it possible to export all styles to the CSS file instead of keep all styles in a  tag using office-ui-fabric-react components?
Webpack could combine all styles into one file.

Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly do you want this? One challenge is that styles are evaluated at runtime, so could have hundreds of permutations. The css file necessary to cover them all would negate any perf gain you feel you might get out of this process.

Past that, we don't have any specific methods for doing this today. It's not just a question of printing the initially loaded styles, but the solution would also require changing classnames upon state changes.

Comment: I just want to have all styles in the one file, for the application structure. Is it possible to export all styles as string and pass it to the MiniCssExtractPlugin?

Or, it's generally better to stick all styles in the style tag?